# How do I prevent my FOR loop from ending too early?

Tags: python, for-loop

CODE:

```
tsol = [6,7,8,9,10]
lenth = len(tsol)

for t,tnext in zip(tsol[0:lenth],tsol[1:lenth]):

  print t,tnext
```

RESULTS:

6,7 
   7,8 
   8,9 
   9,10 
and t value "10" is missing

Comment: Just a side note: you can write `tsol` and `tsol[1:]` instead of `tsol[0:length]` and `tsol[1:length]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use function [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for t,tnext in izip_longest(tsol[0:lenth],tsol[1:lenth]):

  print t,tnext
```

Output:

```
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 None
```

If you want to use a placeholder value different from `None` you can specify the `fillvalue` keyword argument:

```
izip_longest(tsol[0:lenth],tsol[1:lenth], fillvalue="whatever")
```

Output:

```
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
10 whatever
```